# what are steps to make error handler in yii2 advance template ?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a project of yii2 working on , but i have some bugs i dont know how to make debugging for it to fix .

i read some articals about, the mention to add following code

```
     'log' => [
'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
'targets' => [
    'file' => [
        'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
        'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
        'logFile' => '@root/console/runtime/logs/app.log',
    ],
    ],
],
```

but still noting happened and either what is correct please to add this one ?

this quetion for me and for all yii2 beginners

Comment: In which application directory you want to get log? `@root` is not valid [Path Alias](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app/)

Comment: backend/web/index.php?r=students

Comment: Is it your `backend/config/main.php`? If yes then no need to set `logFile` it's default target  is `backend/runtime/logs/app.log`.

Comment: yes 
but where can i find the logs ?

Comment: Check `backend/runtime/logs/app.log`, you have log file there.